# Errors not showing in flask server

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Consider the following minimal flask server

```
import rospy
from flask import Flask, request, Response, make_response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Shutdown is handled by Flask
    rospy.init_node("test", disable_signals=True)
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.errorhandler(Exception)
    def server_error(error):
        print(str(error))
        rospy.logerror(error) # For some reason logerror doesn't work in errorhandler
        return f"Error: {error}", 500

    @app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
    def execute():
        raise Exception("my error")
        return Response(status=200, headers={})

    rospy.loginfo("Starting server...")
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=50002)
```

When POSTing to `127.0.0.1:50002/test`, the following 2 lines are printed

```
my error
500 Internal Server Error: The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

It seems `rospy.logerror` failed and caused another exception to be raised leading to the `500 Internal Server Error`.  Why is this happening and how do I solve this?

PS:: Why is "@ app" converted to "@App" in the post?  This doesn't happen in the preview.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/384372/errors-not-showing-in-flask-server/) by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1083 on 2021-08-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turns out, the issue is due to the typo `logerror` should be `logerr`

But more importantly, the reason more helpful error messages (e.g. `AttributeError` when using `logerror`) aren't appearing is because`rospy.init_node` isn't started in its own thread.  The following should be used instead

```
threading.Thread(target=lambda: rospy.init_node('example_node', disable_signals=True)).start()
```

as mentioned [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/234418/easiest-way-to-implement-http-server-that-can-send-ros-messages/)

---

Originally posted by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) with karma: 1083 on 2021-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0